# Title alignment issue for Android Toolbar

Tags: android-layout, android-toolbar

I am working with the Toolbar for the first time. I am using it as a Actionbar in my application.

I want to align the Toolbar's title to the center. But i realized that there is no in-built method that allows you to do that.

So i added a textview to the Toolbar as follows-

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            **android:gravity="center"**
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="My Title" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

However even this approach does not work since the left edge of my toolbar consists of a drawer menu icon. Hence although my text is center aligned in the textview, the Textview itself does not cover the width of the screen. The output is as follows:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add margin with the same width as the home icon has. I guess

```
android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
```

should be just right.

Comment: adding margin did cross my mind but how will it ensure that the title is center aligned across all devices??

Comment: As long as the margin is the same size as the icon this will perfectly work on any device. And the icon is 56dp. But keep in mind that if you add menu to the toolbar you will need to adjust the margins accordingly. Also note that centered title is against design guidelines.

Comment: I am using your approach as it seems the best way out. Btw from where did you get the menu icon size as 56dp?

Comment: I don't know exactly where the icon size is defined but it is square and toolbar height is 56dp. You should definitely read [Google design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing).

Answer (score -1):

Add your own text view which can be aligned where ever you want :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/green">
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"
 android:text="My Title"
 android:textStyle="bold"/>
```